# What are the contraindications for using Hyper-V with Windows 2012 Server?

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, team-foundation-server, windows-server-2012, hypervisor

**Background:** I am researching several Virtual Machine Manager solutions.  They are being considered for use in separating configuration for multiple development and testing environments.  The decision has already been made to use Windows Server 2012 and to integrate deployment with TFS 2012.

**Question:** Is there anything about what I've said that indicates there would be a problem with using Hyper-V?  Are there any potential incompatibilities that are likely to arise with this configuration or is this an ideal environment for Hyper-V?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: Is there anything about what I've said that indicates there would be a problem with using Hyper-V?

No

> Are there any potential incompatibilities that are likely to arise with this configuration or is this an ideal environment for Hyper-V?

You haven't given any meaningful details, but VMM, Server 2012, TFS, and Hyper-V are all Microsoft products and are capable of doing what you vaguely describe.

Comment: Have you had your coffee yet? ;)

Comment: @MDMarra - Thank you. Please check my related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/441317/where-can-i-learn-fundamentals-about-hypervisors-in-context-of-other-hardware-vi

Comment: @RyanRies actually, I'm home sick today :(