# Where can I learn fundamentals about hypervisors in context of other hardware virtualization solutions?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, hypervisor, supervisord

I am interested in learning more about hardware virtualization, with a specific focus on hypervisors.  I am competent to manage a server and would be able to configure an environment to *work* using this technology, but I don't feel like I have enough background information to make an educated decision about the pros and cons of different aspects of particular implementations.

For those of you who are already very familiar with this topic, Are there any standard articles or white papers I should read about this particular topic?  *(Context: I am currently researching Hyper-V and VMware ESXi, but I am hoping to find more general information about the  context within which these products exist so that I can understand the problems that they aim to solve better than competitive products).*

Comment: Can anyone suggest how I can make this question more site-appropriate?

Answer (score 4):

This question isn't really on topic here, but ill throw you a bone before it gets closed. I assume by ESX you mean ESXi or the vSphere suite of products. ESX is end of life.

I recommend that you visit [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448604.aspx) and [VMWare online training](http://mylearn.vmware.com/portals/www/mL.cfm?menu=topfreecourses) as a start. Then pick up some books or have your employer send you to training.

I recommend Mastering VMWare vSphere 5 by Scott Lowe to anyone wanting to learn the ins-and-outs of vSphere.

Also, set up both in a test lab.

Comment: thanks - Is the book you recommended heavily implementation-specific?  Ideally, the knowledge I'm looking for would carry over to other analogous products

Comment: I don't know what you mean. It's a book on vSphere and covers vSphere deployment from start to finish.

Comment: It is my understanding (potentially wrong) that vSphere and Microsoft's Hyper-V are close to substitutes.  I am hoping to understand the underlying technological principles in addition to how to use a specific product (the VMware/vSphere stack)

Comment: you've got gmail